# Is it possible to join two fisheye images to one equirectangular image using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two fisheye images (one from back and one from front) and i want to join those two images to single equirectangular image.

Is it possible?

the command i am looking for is something this this:

```
ffmpeg -i ./image_from_front.jpg -i ./image_from_back.jpg filters_to_use ./final_single_equirectangular_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible directly. But I was able to do this with ImageMagick and ffmpeg.

To illustrate I take these fisheye images from wikipedia ([original](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DualFisheyePanorama_Room_diagonal.jpg) by Peter.wieden):

[image: fisheye image for back]
[image: fisheye image for front]

First, combine the two fisheye images into one image file:

```
magick ./image_from_front.jpg ./image_from_back.jpg +append ./dual_fisheye_image.jpg
```

[image: dual fisheye]

Then, create the equirectangular image with ffmpeg:

```
./ffmpeg -i ./dual_fisheye_image.jpg -vf v360=input=dfisheye:iv_fov=195:ih_fov=195:output=equirect ./final_single_equirectangular_image.jpg
```

[image: final equirectangular image]

The parameters may need adjustments to match your cameras field of view. Also note that no stiching or blending of the images is performed.

See this [article](http://paulbourke.net/dome/dualfish2sphere/) for general information on the transformations involved and example pictures.

Also see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360 for more information and options of the v360 filter.

Comment: Posting example input and output images would be a great help for others.  Also note in Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: @fmw42 About 'magick convert': I am using ImageMagick 7.1 on windows. There is a windows utility named 'convert'. I thought writing 'magick convert' is available across platforms. Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: For Imagemagick 7, use magick in place of convert. Convert was totally rewritten as magick.  On Windows if you install the legacy components you can use convert, but that will be Imagemagick 6.  If you use magick convert in Imagemagick 7, you will be using convert syntax and may not have available the new features in magick Imagemagick 7. For all other tools in Imagemagick 7, you do need to preface with magick. So magick identify, magick mortify, magick montage, etc. But not magick convert.

Comment: It would be nice to see and example input pair and your result